# adding images in the dynamic listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I'm using the following code for the dynamic ListView.
I need to add some images in fromt of the text in the ListView

```
ListView listView = (ListView) menu.findViewById(R.id.list);
initListView(this, listView, "", 5, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

public  void initListView(Context context, ListView listView, String prefix, int numItems, int layout) {
    // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
    String[] arr ={"A","B","C","D","E"};

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, arr));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know how to add images in my code.

Comment: you can't do that using `ArrayAdapter`. Create a `CustomAdapter` for it. Search for tutorial on [here](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this kind of adapter :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

String[] arr ={"A","B","C","D","E"};
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arr.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int arg0) {
    return arr[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(getItem(arg0));

    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    layout.addView(image);
    layout.addView(text);

    return layout;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using custom adapter you can add images to the listview items look at this tutorial it will help you
 1. [ListView in Android using custom ListAdapter](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/)

2.[Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 1):

As was already suggested, you need to use other Adapters like `SimpleCursorAdapter`

List with images can be quite complex if you want to load images from url also

I highly recomend you look at this code which has full implementation of `ListView` with Images with LazyLoading

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of the LazyList project with quite some additions: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader I'm using it in some projects and its quite good!